# Comparative studies of examples of epizeuxis

Tags: rhetoric, repetition

Epizeuxis is a rhetorical device which is defined as involving immediate or close repetition of a word or phrase - 'Break, break, break, On thy cold grey stones, O sea!' (Tennyson) or 'There's a fox, a fox in the garden' (quoted in [Pilkington](https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=vOfqhnDu1j8C&oi=fnd&pg=PR1&dq=epizeuxis&ots=OhTxnTLTi5&sig=i4N5CTDNXyYhIgiiV41SsDD9Uwc#v=onepage&q=epizeuxis&f=false), p 125).

If we restricted examples to a strict, single-word, immediate repetition pattern based on English language texts, would it be valid to state that:

A: One-syllable patterns are more common than two-or-more-syllable ones;
and, if so, then
B: Examples involving the immediate repetition of two-or-more-syllable words have more impact?
OR
Does the impact depend solely/chiefly on the emotional weight of (a) the term and (b) the term in context?

I am checking various works including Fisher's [Repetition](https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=f6_z7VmZ6A4C&oi=fnd&pg=PA15&dq=epizeuxis&ots=7VcdFDOn8l&sig=sE5sqh_g6u_JmyUQn_CxAYt33VQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) and have not found references to any comparative studies of this type to date. I wondered whether anyone on here might be aware of any specific studies that could provide some answers ... I would be very grateful for any constructive suggestions/pointers.

Comment: Have you tried https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=epizeuxis&oq=epizeux ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried, but failed to find anything so far that addresses the question.

Comment: A feature of repetition is that it makes a rhythm, a beat. So one syllable can only make a simple beat, like a drum: -bam, bam, bam. But a multiple-syllable repetition makes a more complex rhythm - say like the rhythm one hears on a train -‘diddle-de-boom, diddle-de-boom, diddle-de-boom’. Rhythms have an effect on people - they can be soothing (for example, reminiscent of heart-beat) and they are also ‘soothing by familiarity’ - you know, from the rhythmn, what to expect. Politicians frequently have 3 things in their lists in rhetoric in a similar way.  Maybe music/rhythmn studies could help?